# react-native appcenter codepush

Tags: react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push, appcenter

I developed the app with react-native. I'm currently field testing with prod environment. So I'm installing the app as an apk file instead of deploy it to the play store.

Along with app testing, we are also conducting codepush testing. It works well to update the modified content with codepush, but the update sequence is too difficult for me.

Let me give you an example below.

1. build apk -> install apk on physical device
2. Modify a program code (modify 1)
3. codepush update (execute the command below)

```
"appcenter codepush release-react -a {user name}/{app name} -d Production"
```

3. Updated codepush normally on the physical device (modify 1).
4. Modify a program code (modify 2)
5. build apk -> install apk on a physical device  (modify 2)

If I run the app according to the above procedure, the updates deployed in number.2(modify 1) will be reflected in the newly installed app(modify 2). In the newly built app, I want to make sure that the previously distributed codepush(modify 1) is not updated.

If anyone has solutions, I'd greatly appreciate detailed explanations. Thanks.